# Move breadcrumbs on category pages

Tags: category, magento-2.1, breadcrumbs

How to move `breadcrumbs` before `toolbar` on category pages?
I want to show category page `breadcrumbs` before `sort by` dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can display it by below code, put below code to your theme

> Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="content" before="-" />
```

Comment: Tried, but not working.

Comment: Add you file path which you have added code and check first after clean cache. Above code is tested.

Comment: I did the changes in file app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and checked after cleaning the cache but didn't work for me.

Comment: Check after remove var folder.

Comment: Are you check it with layer navigation layout Right?

Comment: How to move breadcrumb to tool bar section?